# How to have a Share option on ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I included Share in my ActionBarSherlock using this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share,
                null, false);

menu.add("Share")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_share_default)
    .setActionView(view1)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

and share.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share_action_provider"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_title_share_default"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"/>

</menu>
```

how can i get all the default option as drop down menu?. like bluetooth, messaging, facebook, linkedin etc and their default implementation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should put the options menu you don't want to appear as actions in the ActionBar as: `android:showAsAction="never".` Then, this automatically will force the overflow menu appear and your options displayed there.

Comment: Yes, that will cause the "3 dots" option appear, that will launch the overflow menu. Like in this screenshot: http://androinica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/dropbox-prepost-ics.png

Comment: okay may be i can use some custom layout to show list and sharing options on it. but how to get the default implementations of messaging, bluetooth etc., which are generally same for all the apps?

Comment: I see. What do you want your application to share? A photo, a document, the link to Goole Play of an app? First figure this out - what you want to share. Then the idea would be to query the device for the applications that can handle the Uri and process it. Store the result in an array, and create the options menu programmatically. **Note that this is an idea, not sure if it's possible, but it's worth investigation**